# How to change URL to asset->sourcePath on Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have folder (e.x.: `/modules/admin/static/`) out of `web/` and I specified sourcePath: `/modules/admin/static/`.

Yii generating assets files in `web/assets/13dfh1/`.

But I want to change this folder to `web/static/assets/13dfh1/`.

I want have url: `http://example.com/static/assets/13dfh1/.`

**`baseUrl`** and **`basePath`** ignored if specified sourcePath.

It's must for another depends, such as YiIAsset, debug, and etc.

Please, help me. 
P.S. Sorry for my egnlish )

Comment: So, if i'm not confused, u only want change assets forlder paths that yii2 generate

Answer (score 1):

If you want change the asset folder you can change the basePath in assetManager in your \config\main.php

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
         'basePath' => '@webroot/your-assets-dir',
     ],
     .......
```

Else  you can do it by the code

```
 \Yii:$app->assetManager->basePath = '@webroot/your-assets-dir';
```

Comment: What path have you assigned? .. I know the answer is right. What path you effectively want  yourApp/web/static/assets/13dfh1/  or other..?

Comment: sourcePath = myApp/modules/admin/static/. I want have generated files over web/static/assets/

Comment: Have you try with @app/modules(admin/static ?